# Possible to Comment on a storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, comments

I recently started working for a company that has me making mockups for an app they'd like to see converted to an iPhone app. I have not been informed as to how all the boards fit together, but I do have a general idea on what they should look like. I would like to write notes or comments on each individual board about how things should be done once I have more information. Is it possible to comment on a board or is there some place close to the boards where I can leave notes on what to do next?

Comment: Anything's possible.  What tool are you using to create the mockups?  (I assume that's where you want to add comments)

Comment: Storyboards are a simple XML format. You can comment the XML itself, and Xcode probably won't get rid of it.

Comment: XCode's storyboard. Maybe Mockup is the wrong word. I have setup the UI in XCode with all the buttons and what not, its just not hooked up to anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interface builder (and, as an extension, Xcode + Storyboards) has a built-in 'notes' section for any object in the hierarchy, which may be exactly what you need:

[image]

Comment: Where is this ever shown though?

Comment: @fatuhoku Why would it ever be shown? Like a comment in source code, its only for the people editing the storyboard.

Comment: Okay — I did't mean 'shown' as in shown in the app.

With comments in source code, you can see them inline, just as you read through the source code.

With the comments box in IB, you can only see the comment 1) when you select the element AND 2) look at the relevant box in the Inspector.

This is what I mean: how on Earth will you know an object on the storyboard has comments at all?  Can you imagine clicking on every object and checking whether the comments box has any useful information in it?

Comment: I had no clue about this!  Handy tip.